# How do I convert an given time like date string to 13 digit timestamp

Tags: java, groovy, timestamp, soapui, ready-api

I want to test an API in `SOAPUI` where I have to send a time request in the format `21 Dec 2016 12:34:45` and the API would fetch me all the records present between the provided start date and end Date.
Now I have to make assertions whether the records are actually present in that date range or not and the response is in 13 digit unix timestamp format. I want to convert `21 Dec 2016 12:34:45` into *13 digit unix timestamp* format.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ ?

Comment: While I don’t know Groovy, if you want to do this in Java 8, I’d prefer to use the new time classes like `DateTimeFormatter` and `Instant` (I’ve heard said they are pretty Joda-inspired).

Comment: Excuse me if this is a dumb question, 13 digit unix timestamp, is that the same as milliseconds since the epoch (as often used in Java)? So depending on time zone the time stamp might be 1482320085000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would need a solution in groovy as the question is marked with `soapui, ready-api` tags.

It is quite simple in groovy:

For instance, you have the date in a variable as shown below in a **Groovy Script** test step.

```
def t = '21 Dec 2016 12:34:45'
```

All you need to do to get the timestamp is :

```
log.info "${new Date(t).getTime()}"
```

[image]

You may assign it to a variable using below statement:

```
def longTime = new Date(t).getTime()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Java build in `Timestamp`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = dateFormat.parse("21 Dec 2016 12:34:45");
long time = date.getTime();
System.out.println(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple date format to convert the date in text to Date variable. Then you can use Date.getTime method.

21 Dec 2016 12:34:45 = dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss

You should be able to code the rest.